Story about genetically mutated children who escape from a compound in Colorado into the mountains, where they grow wings
The story is about genetically mutated children who escape from a compound in Colorado into the mountains, where they grow wings and the breast plate like a bird they can fly and a man finds in and helping.
If anybody knows the title of the story, please tell me. I’ve been looking for like 10 years.

Is this a novel, a short story in an anthology, or a movie?

"a man finds in and helping" Did you mean to say that a man finds them and helps them?

Birds don't wear or grow breast plates. Can you clarify what you meant by that?

Sounds like the Maximum Ride book series by James Patterson. They made a movie of the first book.

As stated in the comments by @ArlettaS, this sounds like the Maximum Ride series by James Patterson.
The series was, in fact, a reboot of Patterson's earlier adult novel When the Wind Blows and it's sequel The Lake House.

Frannie Devin O'Neill is a veterinarian living in Bear Bluff, Colorado, whose husband was killed three years ago. She meets Kit Harrison, an FBI agent, when he rents a cabin in the woods behind her house. Kit is investigating a case in which Frannie's husband may be implicated. One night, after a friend's mysterious death, Frannie sees a small girl with wings, running in the forest. As she is growing closer to Kit, Frannie tells him about the winged girl. They search for her and manage to catch her. She tells them that her name is Max. She and her brother Matthew grew up as experiments in a sinister lab known as the "School", and were separated during their escape. Max guides Kit and Frannie back to the School. They break in and find the rest of Max's "flock", winged children named Peter, Wendy, Icarus, and Oz.

